# PHP's imagejpeg function isn't outputting an image

Tags: php, image

I'm using PHPs imagecreatefromjpeg to load a jpeg from disk and imagejpeg to output that image to the browser.  For some reason though, this function is only outputting the image when the server is running on a Windows development box.  On our Linux server, its not outputting any data (ie. Content-Length: 0, nothing is displayed).

Are there any workarounds that make this work on a Linux box?  I've confirmed that the GD library is installed with jpeg support.

Comment: It works fine on Linux - check your error logs.  I'd guess it's failing to load the file - check paths and permissions

Answer (score 1):

There are two notes on http://php.net/imagejpeg which may be relevant:

> Notes
>
> Note: JPEG support is only available
> if PHP was compiled against GD-1.8 or
> later.
>
> Note: If you want to output
> Progressive JPEGs, you need to set
> interlacing on with imageinterlace().

Also some actual code would be useful in attempting to help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct [file permissions](http://www.freeos.com/articles/3127/) set.  Does your web service own the file?  Does it have permission to read or write the file?